# Computing the limit of this function

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals, infinity

So I have an improper integral:

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{13x}{x^2+1}-\frac{65}{5x+1} dx
$$

I have solved the integral into this:

$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{13}{2}\ln{|x^2+1|}-13\ln{|5x+1|}\bigg)\bigg|_0^t
$$

I thought the answer should be infinity since $\ln\infty$ is infinity. But it turns out that it is not and the solution is [$-13\ln5$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ekoc3hrccs6).

Why is that?

Comment: Well, you also have $-13ln|5x+1|$

Comment: @dani_s he does, but he also has $\frac{13}{2}\ln|x^2+1|$...

Comment: @5xum his argument is "ln $\infty$ is infinity"; he should also consider that "-ln $\infty$ is -infinity" :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{13}{2}\ln{|x^2+1|}-13\ln{|5x+1|}\bigg)|_0^t=\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{13}{2}\ln\left(\frac{(t^2+1)}{(5t+1)^2}\right)=-13\ln 5
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response! Didn't realize I can combine them into one. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

$$\frac{13}{2}\ln|x^2+1| - 13\ln |5x+1|= \frac{13}{2}\left(\ln\left|\frac{x^2+1}{(5x+1)^2}\right|\right)$$

to expose the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Without actually computing messy antiderivatives:

$$ \dfrac{13 x}{x^2 + 1} - \dfrac{65}{5x+1} = \dfrac{1}{x} \left(\dfrac{13}{1 + 1/x} - \dfrac{13}{1+ 1/(5x)} \right) = O(1/x^2)$$

so it is integrable at $\infty$, i.e. the answer will be finite.